# Error in creating the empty data frame with Timestamp as column but without name

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

The study requires a temporary data frame to store values, but unable to do so. Kindly help.

```
temp_df<- data.frame(TIMESTAMP= as.POSIXct("0000-00-00 00:00:00", format="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), qs= numeric(0))
```

The error appears as

```
Error in data.frame(TIMESTAMP = as.POSIXct("0000-00-00 00:00:00", format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Kindly help in creating dataframe- with 1st column does not have name but contains the values in form of timestamp and 2nd column having name contains fractional values.

Comment: @akrun..Many thanks for the help.It works now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an empty data.frame with specific `class` as

```
df1 <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP=as.POSIXct(character()), qs=numeric(0))
```